# Field Name Best Practices (Shadowing or Compund Names)

Tags: shadowing, field-names

As the red block above (warning that this is a subjective question and may be closed) there may not be a stone etched law on this, but I don't see why that would warrant closing a question.

...Rant aside

I am planning on implementing Hibernate as my persistence framework, which may fix my problem upon implementation, but I have DB tables that translate into class and sub-class (many specifics and complications that exist in real life are omitted :) ):

```
//dbo.a with column Name
class a {
  public String Name;
}

//dbo.b with column Name and a foreign key to dbo.a
class b extends a {
  public String Name;
}
```

So, for the what should be done and why:

Shadowing:
I could leave these as is, which would require some reflection cleverness (per http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5419973 ), when working with objects whose types are unknown at compile.

Compound Names:
I could name all of my fields preceded by its class's name i.e. `a.aName` and `b.bName`, which gets really ugly in real life: `Door.DoorName` and `RotatingDoor.RotatingDoorName`

Getters and Setters:
I didn't mention this one, since with JavaBeans these will be derived from the field names, and I believe Hibernate uses annotated POJOs.

To influence the results a little, shadowing seems to be the most robust, at least in my case where class `a` extends an abstract class with `Name` defined, then `b` shadows with its own `Name` when applicable. Using compound names would mean that if I wanted to add a `NickName` column to all my DB tables then I would have to add that field to each type (and then what's the point of inheritance?!)

In the end I decided to find out what people, hopefully who have experienced pros/cons of an implementation of one or more of these technique, have to say on the issue; or that convenient stone etched best practice will do :)

-Nomad311

Answer (score 0):

you should only define your member in the base class if you need it in all subclasses. hibernate offers various types of mappings for class trees. take a look at [Inheritance mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) in the manual to get a feeling of it.

you can define your mapping either via an xml file or via annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, over the break I'll check that out and read up on Hibernate. I'm glad I didn't devote any time to my data tier yet ...It would have sucked to implement one of theses solutions to find it wasn't compatible with Hibernate or possibly any other persistence framework!